# Deploying services to multiple nodetypes

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a stateful service with more than 10 partitions.  I want to deploy this service into multiple node types in a service fabric cluster.  Each node type is a VMSS scale set of 5 nodes.  How I can write the override constraints with OR condition?

Comment: To be clear, you have an application with only one service? And you want to deploy this service trough, multiple node groups? Can I ask you why do you want to do that?

Comment: There are many services running in my Service Fabric Cluster.  Each scale set has 5 nodes.  Since I have more than 5 partitions, i want to make use of other node types which are not fully utilized.  That's why I want to deploy them to multiple nodetypes